# Allow sender spoofing for specific user on Postfix server with LDAP

Tags: email, postfix, email-server

So I have a Postfix server that authenticates users against an LDAP directory.

This works great so far, but one of the mail adresses should be allowed to set another sender address.

All users on that server already are limited to send with their login adress, e.g. 
`john@example.com` is only allowed to send with that exakt mail adress.

The only exeption should be one adress, `admin@example.com`, which should be allowed to send with *any* sender address(not limited to `example.com`).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this with `Postfix Restriction Classes`. You can add restriction classes as shown below.

```
#/etc/postfix/main.cf
smtpd_restriction_classes = restrictive, permissive
restrictive = reject_sender_login_mismatch
permissive = permit
smtpd_sender_restrictions =  check_sender_access regexp:/etc/postfix/admin_only
smtpd_sender_login_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_maps

#/etc/postfix/admin_only
/^admin@example.com$/  permissive
/^/                    restrictive

#/etc/postfix/sender_maps
user@example.com  user@example.com
```

Here `reject_sender_login_mismatch` restriction  will not be applicable for `admin@example.com` user. The above configuration is using `hash` lookup table for `smtpd_sender_login_maps`. You can use `LDAP` or any other lookup table of your choice. Hope that helps.

Ref: [Postfix Docs](http://www.postfix.org/RESTRICTION_CLASS_README.html)

Comment: So what exactly is the `permissive`/`restrictive` for? And what happens, if an account is not listed in either of the maps?

Comment: You can call `restrictive/permissive` as names of restriction classes you have. I updated the answer to use `regexp` lookup type for `check_sender_access`. So you need not add all your email addresses in `/etc/postfix/admin_only`. For this logic to work, `smtpd_sender_login_maps` should be proper. More about it [here](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_sender_login_maps)

Comment: Beware: This allows any user one to send with admin address, instead of allowing the admin user to send with any address

Comment: The correct restriction would be check_sasl_access in smtpd_client_restrictions